# Kubernetes Pod Dynamic Environment Variables

Tags: controller, kubernetes, environment-variables

I need to be able to assign custom environment variables to each replica of a pod. One variable should be some random uuid, another unique number. How is it possible to achieve? I'd prefer continue using "Deployment"s with replicas. If this is not feasible out of the box, how can it be achieved by customizing replication controller/controller manager? Are there hooks available to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> If this is not feasible out of the box, how can it be achieved by customizing replication controller/controller manager? Are there hooks available to achieve this?

Your best bet is a mixture of an `initContainer:` and/or a custom -- possibly overridden -- entrypoint `command:`. The Pods are all going to be carbon copies of each other, except for their names and a few other trivial changes. Any per-Pod specific behavior is the responsibility of the containers in the Pod themselves.

```
containers:
- image: whatever
  command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
      export RANDOM_UUID=`uuidgen`
      export UNIQ=/usr/bin/generate-some-awesome-sauce
      exec /usr/local/bin/dockerfile-entrypoint.sh or whatever else
```

Comment: What happens inside container is outside of my reach. So "/usr/bin/generate-some-awesome-sauce" is not really available.

Comment: It's never outside your reach, as kubernetes is a container orchestrator. But, you will observe I also mentioned `initContainers:`, so use that to run `image: super-sekrit-generator:1`, and volume mount an `emptyDir: {}` between the two containers, and use _that_ to inject into the main container's environment. That said, if you are 100% opposed to overriding the `command:` then you are in for a lot of pain

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into that tomorrow! By any chande the stateful sets can make this easier? Looks like they have ordinance index automatically polulated.

Comment: With a StatefulSet, you would still have to extract the ordinance index from the pod, which you can do in an initContainer.

Comment: How can I pass the ordinance index from initContainer to compute container? I would like to avoid using volumes. Can I write into environment variables? I trued using "export" command but it didnt work.

Comment: What does "tried using export but it didn't work" mean? And with a `StatefulSet`, I'm pretty sure the ordinal is the trailing digit of the Pod's name, which you can get via `hostname` or through the downward API mentioned by Jordan in his answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the downward API to inject the metadata.uid of the pod as an envvar, which is unique per pod

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl run hello  --restart Never --image busybox  -- /bin/sh -c  "while true; do echo \$RANDOM; sleep 1;done"
```

or

kubectl run busybox --image busybox --env=random=$RANDOM --restart Never -- /bin/sh -c "echo \$random"

This works fine

```
[root@master 41-jobs]# kubectl logs hello
```

> 3298
>
> 16447
>
> 9517
>
> 3082
>
> 32611
>
> 19179
>
> 21098
>
> 12943