# Pass current date to kubernetes cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I have a docker image that receive an env var name `SINCE_DATE`.
I have created a cronjob to run that container and I want to pass it the current date.

How can I do it?

Trying this, I get the literal string `date -d "yesterday 23:59"`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
          - name: my-cron
            image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
            imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
            env:
            - name: SINCE_DATE
              value: $(date -d "yesterday 23:59")
```

Comment: if you are using helm, [this might be a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968757/append-release-timestamp-to-helm-template-name/51983330#51983330).

Comment: but helm just build the cronjob object for the first time, it just populate it with the date when I created the job... I want it to be defined for every new run

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve and how? As you have container crated it has it won time (depends on your env its local env, cloud, virtual) time might be bit different. More details [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/tick-tock-container-time). Your cronjob will create pod each minute. You want to pass one value all the time or date value each minute?

Comment: date value each minute. I want to pass the `SINCE_DATE` as what is the current time. Every minute the container is executed with a new (updated) `SINCE_DATE`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by `overwriting container` [Entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) command and set `environment variable`.
In your case it would looks like:

```
          containers:
          - name: my-cron
            image: nginx
            #imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
            command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                  export SINCE_DATE=`date -d "yesterday 23:59"`
                  exec /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**Note:**

Nginx `docker-entrypoint.sh` in located in `/` If your image have different path, you should use it, for example `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

Very similar use-case can be found in [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844291/kubernetes-pod-dynamic-environment-variables/53845647)

**What does this solution?**

It will `overwrite` default script set in the container `ENTRYPOINT` with the same script but beforehand set dynamically environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem recently using [KubeMod](https://github.com/kubemod/kubemod), which patches resources as they are created/updated in K8S. It is nice for this use case since it requires no modification to the original job specification.

In my case I needed to insert a date into the middle of a previously existing string in the spec, but it's the same concept.

For example, this matches a specific job by regex, and alters the second argument of the first container in the spec.

```yaml
apiVersion: api.kubemod.io/v1beta1
kind: ModRule
metadata:
  name: 'name-of-your-modrule'
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Patch
  match:
    - select: '$.metadata.name'
      matchRegex: 'regex-that-matches-your-job-name'
    - select: '$.kind'
      matchValue: 'Job'
  patch:
    - op: replace
      path: '/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/1'
      select: '$.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args[1]'
      value: '{{ .SelectedItem | replace "Placeholder Value" (cat "The time is" (now | date "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00")) | squote }}'
```